# MicroK8s Pods can not Access MongoDb from in a Multi-Server Environment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, microservices, mongodb

I have 2 different servers running on Ubuntu 22.04. The local IP of my server A is 192.168.1.3 On this server I am running MongoDB on docker. I can connect to MongoDB from outside with MongoCompas.

The local IP of my server B is 192.168.3.6 and microk8s is installed on this server. The servers can access each other. For example, I can telnet 192.168.1.3 to port 27017. However, I cannot access MongoDB from the pods on microk8s. I get a timeout error.

What I tried I created an endpoint. I could not access through the endpoint either. I created microk8s network policy, but again I could not access.

I am trying to access MongoDB from my .NET 7 API application.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dbacces
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: db1.example.com
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: externaldb
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.1.3
    ports:
      - port: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: externaldb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: externaldb
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-from-microk8s
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: mongodb
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: microk8s
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 27017
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
    - {}
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
```